# General structure in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to object oriented languages (programming in VBA for years) and having a hard time switching into it (no native-english speaker .. sorry for upcoming mistakes)

Here is my very first program where i want to test different things. Running my VSC Debugger i got an error in line 7(file: 'file:///c%3A/python/test.py' severity: 'Fehler' message: 'E0001:expected an indented block (, line 7)') . But i think it´s a more general problem. Is the general structure OK? Importing first, then defining 2 Functions?

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

```
import ctypes
import random

def main():
    rndNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    MBoxString = "is this a good Number? "+ rndNumber
    Mbox("Number", MBoxString, 1)
    varContinue = int(input("1 for yes & 2 for no! "))
    while varContinue == 2:
        rndNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
        print("Is this a better one?", rndNumber)
        varContinue = int(input("1 for yes & 2 for no! "))



def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: Indentation needs to be fixed. Other than that, structure is fine; python works top down.

Comment: Line 6 should be `"is this a good Number? "+ str(rndNumber)`, you cannot concatenate numbers with string that way, unless you convert the number to strings first using `str()`.

Comment: But Nico said its coming in line 7

Comment: @Harry I'm not saying the error the OP is talking about is in line 6, I'm just pointing out another error that I saw.

Comment: @Nico May you tell me if you are using windows or linux. May you add the error in the question

Comment: amazing fast answears! 
The Error: file: 'file:///c%3A/python/test.py'
severity: 'Fehler'
message: 'E0001:expected an indented block (<string>, line 7)'
at: '7,1'
source: 'pylint'

I added the "str()" thing in line 8 but it doesnt fix the rest..

Comment: Well I guess I am not getting the error because its already indented properly during edits. So I guess the problem is already solved. unless you are getting "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'" you have minor problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked:
Changes made :

```
MBoxString = "is this a good Number? "+ str(rndNumber)
```

Code :

```
import ctypes
import random

def main():
    rndNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    MBoxString = "is this a good Number? "+ str(rndNumber)
    Mbox("Number", MBoxString, 1)
    varContinue = int(input("1 for yes & 2 for no! "))
    while varContinue == 2:
        rndNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
        print("Is this a better one?", rndNumber)
        varContinue = int(input("1 for yes & 2 for no! "))

def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

main()
```

Comment: it was so easy ... i just had to add a an insertion for the whole main-function ... it runs now. Thanks to everyone!